# HTTP POST Request not Working in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple MVC application and have created html table in view. When i click on hyperlink under this table it does not take me to the [HttpPost] method and goes to [HttpGet] default method. Please take a look on my table placed in view portion of my mvc application.

```
@model   Mvc.Affiliates.Models.Products
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Details</h2>
<div style="height: 200px; width: 500px">
    <h1>This is Content page </h1>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
          <table  border="1" style="width:550px;">
          <tr>
                <th><a href="#" data-sortfield="CustomerID">Job Id</a></th>
                <th><a href="#" data-sortfield="CompanyName">Job Name</a></th>
                <th><a href="#" data-sortfield="ContactName">Create Date</a></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model.JobList)
            {
             <tr>
               <td width="50px">@item.JobId</td>
                <td width="200px">@item.JobName</td>
                <td width="200">@item.CreateDate</td>

             </tr>
            }

        </table>
        <br />
        <table border="1" style="width: 550px; ">
          @{ 
             int i = Model.JobList.Count;
             i = i / 10;
             i = i + 1;

              <tr>
               <td width="450">
                @for(int n = 1; n <= i; n++)
                {
                 @Html.ActionLink(n.ToString(), "Index", "Home", new { id = n});
                 @Html.Raw(" ");
            }
               </td>
              </tr>
          }  
        </table>      
    }
</div>
```

So my above view @Html.ActionLink() is not working well. Please anyone help that how can i force my ActionLink to go into `[HttpPost]` method.

EDIT:
I have pasted complete view above. I am actually creating gridview with paging and when i click on page number (whcih is an ActionLink in numeric values) i need to run [HttpPost] method, thanks.

Comment: This is the default behaviour...actionlink generates anchor tag in html and anchors can't submit the form..anchor tag will hit httpget always if you want to hit httppost use submit button inside a form.

Comment: Thats what a link does. If you want to go to the POST method, you need a form and submit it. But what would be the point - you not editing anything and the parameter in your POST method is `MyProducts ` and nothing in your view could bind to that anyway. Unclear what your trying to achieve,

Comment: you can not do that..if you want post some data using action link then you have to use `ajax post`

Comment: And another thing. You are submitting id not model. You have taken model in post method

Comment: Please view my EDIT portion of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't post by doing this.

1. Action link is GET Method.
2. Even if you manage to make it to be POST method, right now your action link Does Post nothing / not the `MyProducts model` you want it to post.

**Solution:**

1. Reconsider your view design
2. Using ajax ( jquery ) to post it. Below is some snippet:

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "Json",
    url: '/Home/Index",
    data: @yourmodel
});`

**EDIT:** Modify the OP View for clear explanation:

- If you plan to use `Html.BeginForm`, then instead of `@Html.ActionLink`, you should use `<input type="submit" />`.
  By this way, it will appear as a button, instead of a link.
  It will send a post that contain `Products object` to your server.
- If you plan to use Ajax, you don't need the `Html.BeginForm` to post. I suggest you read this post to understand clearly: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages

Comment: @Jacy I am new to mvc and ajax. Can you please edit my view to place ajax code in it, thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: @RaufAbid Please read edit in my answer. It will take some time to modify your code in order to use Ajax approach. Just read about it first before using it. The link in my answer have an example so you can try to follow it

Comment: I am following your provided link, I welcome if you provide any code to accomplish my task :).

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ActionLink(n.ToString(), "Index", "Home", new { id = n}) is a get request
Your method is expecting id 
So Better edit like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{

    return View();
}
```